# Results for ggplot in r shiny

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, shiny, visualization

Why does the output plot for the ggplot is not showing in the output?What is the problem with the following code? It doesn't produce any error but it does shows the ggplot graph in ui.In r shiny the data flow is very difficult, since i'm a beginner

[image]

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Stock prediction"),
  sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  textInput(inputId = "stock_name",label = "Enter the stock name",value = "MSFT"),
  textInput(inputId = "stock_history",label = "How many days back would you like your data to go back to help make the prediction?",value = "compact")
),
mainPanel(
  h2("Stock data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("data_table"),
  renderPlot("plot_high")
)
)
))
```

server.R

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(alphavantager)
library(ggplot2)
data <- function(stock_name="",days_history){
  av_api_key("YOUR_API_KEY")
  sri <- data.frame(av_get(symbol = stock_name, av_fun = "TIME_SERIES_DAILY", interval = "15min", outputsize = "compact"))
  sri
}
visualization <- function(sri){
  high_vis <- ggplot(aes(x = timestamp, y = high),data = sri) +     geom_freqpoly(stat = "identity") + 
labs(title = "High price vs Time",x = "Timeline in months",y = "Share price - High") + 
theme_classic(base_size = 20)
  high_vis
}
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$data_table <-     renderDataTable({data(input$stock_name,input$stock_history)})
  output$plot_high <- renderPlot({visualization(data_table)})
})
```

Comment: Have you tried printing the object, e.g. `print(high_vis)`?

Comment: Yup, I tried to print it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

Replace

- `renderPlot("plot_high")` by `plotOutput("plot_high")` in ui.R
- `visualization(data_table)` by
  `visualization(data(stock_name=input$stock_name, input$stock_history))` in server.R

You may also want to remove `DT::` in  `DT::dataTableOutput("data_table")`. For some reason, `dataTableOutput` function from `DT` package is not working for me (so I used the same function but directly from `shiny`).

**EDIT**

It might be clearer to you to rewrite `shinyServer` as:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  data_table <- reactive({data(stock_name=input$stock_name, input$stock_history)})
  output$data_table <- renderDataTable({data_table()})
  output$plot_high <- renderPlot({visualization(data_table())})
})
```

---

Note that `input$stock_history` (`days_history`) is not used (and could be removed) in the provided code for `data()` function.

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks :)  ,The days_history variable is planned for future use !

Comment: But why can't we use `data_table` instead of `data(stock_name=input$stock_name, input$stock_history)`...what causes the problem ? I don't get it

Comment: Because `data_table` is an output. I have edited the answer with a proposal for `shinyServer` that you might find clearer.

Comment: Now i can undersatand